# How to read and edit buttons in main event loop

Tags: python, button, kivy

I've got a grid of buttons and need a way to read the properties of a specific button and edit properties of another in the main event loop.

I've looked up a bunch of different ways to edit properties and i can on startup or by manually writing out 12 button widgets all with a specific name, but i obviosuly would like to keep it a bit more general.

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
kivy.require("1.11.1")

#Force window size
Config.set('graphics','width','150')
Config.set('graphics','height','200')

class ButtonField(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ButtonField, self).__init__()
        self.cols = 3
        self.rows = 4
        for count in list(range(self.cols*self.rows)):
            self.btn = ToggleButton(id=str(count))
            self.add_widget(self.btn)


class Ditto(App):
    def build(self):
        return ButtonField()

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)

    def update(self, *args):
        print("test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Ditto().run()
```

here's the .kv file.

```
<ToggleButton>

    id: btns
    group: 'Field'
    font_size: 40
    background_color: 1,1,1,1
    disabled_color: 1, 0.64, 0, 1
    background_normal: ''
    background_disabled_down: ''
    text: '' if btns.state == 'normal' else 'O'
    disabled: False if btns.state == 'normal' else True
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
```

I wanted to turn one of the buttons background colour red every 3 seconds or so, and if the button was red and clicked then you loose. hence the read and edit buttons.

p.s. is there an on_first or on_action or something, just so the schedule can start only after a button has been pressed rather than on startup that would be wonderful. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read the button property from `.kv` file to `.py` file, then you would need to use the `ObjectProperty`

in .kv file

```
id: btns
group: 'Field'
.
.
.
```

in .py file

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
```

when you write this

```
self.btn = ToggleButton(id=str(count))
```

you need to read the `btn` from the `kv` file. To achieve this,

```
btns=ObjectProperty(None)
self.btns = ToggleButton(id=str(count))
```

Please note that the variable name `btns` should be the same as in `id (kv file)`